# Why doesn't TypeScript complain when I add extra properties to an interface?

Tags: typescript

```
type MyType = {
  propertyOne: string
  propertyTwo: number
}

export const someFunction = (line: MyType[]): MyType[] => {
  return line.map((t) => ({
    ...t,
    someAdditionalProperty: 'why is this legal',
  }))
}
```

Why is someAdditionalProperty allowed here? How to disallow it?

```
type MyType = {
  propertyOne: string
  propertyTwo: number
}

export const someFunction = (line: MyType[]): MyType[] => {
  const someVariable: MyType[] =  line.map((t): MyType => ({
    ...t,
    someAdditionalProperty: 'why is this legal',
  }))
  return someVariable
}
```

This complains, but still it seems like a lot of work to do this for all of my functions with a map or any other Array.prototype function.

Comment: Look up "excess property checks". Those properties aren't accessible through the interface anyway, so to a certain extent they don't matter.

Comment: Typescript can't do this in most cases, for various reasons. A better question is why do you care about this?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript allows this because it uses [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). As long as a given type has all the members of an expected type it is compatible.
Typescript will only error out on extra properties in a very limited set of cases.

There's also good reasons for allowing this, otherwise things like are not possible:

```
interface Pet {
  owner: string
}

interface Dog extends Pet {
  name: string
}

function owner(pet: Pet): string {
  return pet.owner;
}

const fluffy: Dog = { owner: "John", name: "Fluffy" }

// This is only possible due to subtyping
const fluffyOwner = owner(fluffy);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `const` variable syntax typescript tries to check types before computations. But if you use only arrow functions there is no precomputed result to check, that's strange.

So the solution is to use `typescript 4.9` and above and use new feature named `satisfies` exactly for this kind of cases.

Your code with it:

```
export const someFunction = (line: MyType[]) => {
  return line.map<MyType>((t) => ({
    ...t,
    someAdditionalProperty: 'why is this legal',
  } satisfies MyType))
}
```

And now wrong typing error is displayed.