# Use Typescript to restrict return object to not allow additional properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have the following function written in typescript.

```js
const creator = <T,>(func: () => T) => {}
```

And I use it as described below.

```js
creator<{ foo: string }>(() => ({
    foo: 'some string...'
}))
```

But when I add additional properties to the return object of the provided function, typescript does not give an error.

```js
creator<{ foo: string }>(() => ({
    foo: '',
    bar: 'this should not be allowed!' // <--- should give error
}))
```

How can I edit the `creator` function to make sure typescript show the additional properties as an error?

Please see the following typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJQCcCmBDW4nwLzwDwAqANAHwAUAZgK6SgBc85AlLqfIazuwN4gC+IZOkxJ8PeJXDhGcJAEtIAc3j8KLNkz7wdk6YwDkB4sF3wARmiSHYAC3nR40W+GoAbACbxI4BOZTwaG5u4ADuKB4AhAbwAPSxBAC0yU4u7l5K8gBuAShISFjA-MzMwEA).

Edit: I don’t know how to use the Exact type in the answer provided in the post recommended. I do not in any way feel this answers my question!

Please reopen!

At the very least, (if you close it) please show me how to implement the Exact type as I only have one parameter, and it takes two.

Comment: also: [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497299/typescript-prevent-assignment-of-object-with-more-properties-than-is-specified) and [Why doesn't TypeScript complain when I add extra properties to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697907/why-doesnt-typescript-complain-when-i-add-extra-properties-to-an-interface)