# Use typescript to infer function parameter based on declared function return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to infer the type of a function parameter, based on the declared function return type?

```js
type MyFunc = any // <--- How to implement?

const myFunc: MyFunc = (param): { foo: boolean } => {
  return { foo: true }             // ^ this should define the type of param
            // ^ no excess properties allowed here!
}
```

UPDATE: I would like to implement the `MyFunc` type in such a way, that if I hover over the `param` argument, the type that would be shown would be `boolean`, just becouse the declared type of the function is `boolean`.

Is this possible?

[See this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASlAJgVwMZQE4wLwwDwDKANDAIIxQAeIUAdogM4wCGtYAfABQMjM0BcMYi1QgAlgHtag0gEoc7IcGCopPGKgxQ+UBCnRZceACpEuW-ZkHH52RQG9gMZzC0hkGWq6RpMwAL7Kmto0er4YnNy8NLKC9jAAZhISggBGyQA22l7+CjDxAPQFMADuABZgMGJMIGWwPDowEMwYzAC2UDRYtBIg+YnJaZnZMIHObh5e8UkpMCAYyLCB-rJAA).

ANOTHER UPDATE: I edited the return type from `boolean` to `{ foo: boolean }`. I do not want the return type to allow excess properties.

Comment: ① Please edit your code to match the playground ② This isn't currently possible and probably will never be; your example *might* be supported as a future improvement for [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) as `true` does not depend on `param`.  But if you change it slightly to a function that uses `param` somewhere in its body to determine the return type, then it's a circularity the compiler will probably never allow.  You should just annotate the param as `boolean`.  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: -1 for editing the question in a way that invalidates an existing answer. That is **extremely rude** to the individual(s) who spent their time working on an answer to your original question. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: ③ "I do not want the return type to allow excess properties." Excess properties will always be allowed, there's not much you can do about it. At best you can discourage it, but this is mostly off topic for a question about generics. Also, please demonstrate what you're talking about, or else someone might say [they can't reproduce it](https://tsplay.dev/NdO7nw)

Comment: Ok, If its not possible good to know. When it comes to "Excess properties" it seems to me that the return type is defined on the actual function, it will not allow excess types. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIBmBXSp4F54AoCUAueAbyXHEICMyAbAUwENJ4BfTAPmOHngCdbZkPJkS7dS5eLB7JaAGlHcK9HoQDkAC1rVq4VfAD0++AB4AtOfiRwCetvAB3WgBNRzYG6A). If the the return type is the same as the param, as it is in redux reducers, the it would be great to just define the type 1 time. That is the bacground for the question. Thank you for the answers:)

Comment: Also, Im sorry to be rude. Sometimes it is frustrating writing questions becouse they often get closed really fast, thus I might have been a bit careless in how fast i posted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053498/use-typescript-to-restrict-return-object-to-not-allow-additional-properties) is an example related to this question that was closed fast, which was frustrating to me.

Comment: I *would* write up an answer with ms/TS#47599, since that's the underlying thing preventing this, but the excess properties edit really seems out of scope and nothing about inferring function parameters would affect that one way or another.  You could change your function to discourage (not totally prevent) excess properties like [this](//tsplay.dev/NryMaw), but if that's what you're looking for you should [edit] the question or ask a new question about *that* instead of talking about contextual inference of the function parameter.  As it stands now this is effectively multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it quite the way you want to. It would require a generic, and you'd run into the classic "Type '{foo: boolean}' is not assignable to type 'T'...'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{foo: boolean}'." error ([like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigHgCoD4AKMAQwCcSBbALilwEpN86BuAKDYHpOpeoA3QEhEwwVACiZMgHsyUagFpCbVFOQBnYFEoIUqWnCRpMUYuSr1aAbwBmUqbQBGdgDYQSyAL5MoltnyhkEMCIZMg+tvZQwGSIEB7s8UA)).

But if you move your `{foo: boolean}` from the function return to the constant's type annotation, you don't run into that problem:

```typescript
type MyFunc<T> = (param: T) => T;

const myFunc: MyFunc<{foo: boolean}> =    (param) => {
// Move here −−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^− instead of ^
    return {foo: true};
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwDwBUB8UC8UAFGAIYBOJAtgFxSYCU+umA3AFBuoD2yAzsFEoIUqWnCRp0AbwBmXLrQBG8gDYQSyAL64CxclUZ5cUtlDNQyEYIjLIos+bWBlEETe3dA)

---

In the edit after this answer was posted, you said you wanted to avoid excess properties on the returned object (in fact, originally it wasn't an object at all). That's a fundamentally different question and should be asked separately (if it hasn't already been). Note that excess property checks are *very* narrowly applied in TypeScript. I don't know the exact details, but the types have to be defined *very* closely (in type terms) to where the assignment/return occurs for excess property checks to occur.

To give you an idea how narrowly they're applied, they apply here ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOMC8MAUAlAFwwDeAZiCKQEbVZJgwC+uAfOQFAy8wBOcKAFd+zStVJR+wuABoYtJP1IUkGCHBYBuLjqA)):

```typescript
const example = (): {foo: boolean } => {
    return {foo: true, bar: false};
    //                 ^− Type '{ foo: true; bar: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: boolean; }'.
    //                      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type '{ foo: boolean; }'.
};
```

...but not here ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQGIFcB2BjYASwHscoBeKACgEoKA+KAbwDNjiAuKAI3fQTIBfANwAoPKQDOwKBEQp0XeMjSZcBEmUq0GzUVANQAThGBYjZVuy7AjWCABoeCI1xYJUkiCNGCgA)):

```typescript
type ExampleFunction = () => {foo: boolean };
const example: ExampleFunction = () => {
    return {foo: true, bar: false};
    // No error here −−^
};
```

I doubt you can get them to apply to your situation, but again, that's a separate question to the question that was asked and answered originally.

Comment: Thank you, but if I do this, the return type of the function would allow excess properties. I do noy want that.

Comment: @johann1301s no it doesn't, the return type is just `boolean`. Try `const foo = myFunc(true);`, you'll see the type of `foo` is just `boolean`. The `T` is constrained by the concrete type argument.